# Find strings in database (not exact match)

Tags: php, mysql, string, substring

I have a table in a mysql db, in which I have a field for the first name and a field for the last name of persons.

Also I have a text that is stored in another table.

It is possible that some of the names are also part of the texts.

I want to search the text for the names and build links around these names in the text before I output the text.

It is possible that the names in the text are written in different way:

- first name last name
- last name, first name
- first letter of first name. last name
- last name only

How can I achieve that there is only one link around the most complete string.
For example: I don't want to have a link around first name last name and within that a link around last name again.

*EDIT*: I tried to store all possible combinations for all names in an array. Afterwards I search for these combinations in the text. The problem I have is that I find for example "John Doe" and genarate a link, but I also find "Doe" and there is also a link generated, which results in the following: "link"John "link"Doe"/link""/link"

Thank you and best regards

Comment: And what you have tried???

Comment: Full table + text searching... hmz, call me old fashioned, but MySQL tables are at their most useful when you don't have to search _all_ of the data each time you query. Either way: Have you tried `fielname LIKE '%someString%'`?

Comment: Have you investigated the use of MySQL's `FULLTEXT` search system?

Comment: I edited the question to explain what I have tried so far. I can't use the LIKE pattern or the fulltext search, because it doesn't solve the problem that I have to link only the most complete name string.